# I need to find how to differentiate between usb is connected and card reader is also connected to target in linux

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, sh, embedded-linux

I have searched many commands but those are not working i want a command which will detect my usb and card reader and tell me that for example sda is usb and sdc is card reader what i have used is

**OUTPUT**

`$(lsblk -l -o name | grep sd | head -n 1)`

```
cat /sys/block/$OUTPUT/device/{vendor,model}
```

but this will only giving me usb name. I want some logic which will give me that sda is usb and sdb is card readers (using shell scripting)
please help me for this thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably use udev for this.

Comment: perhaps try `lsub`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
lsblk -dno name,subsystems
```

and see if your card reader is differentiate.